# on windows 7 64bit, how much address space can a 32bit program access?

Tags: windows, 32bit-64bit

when using the LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag, can my 32bit program access 4GB of address space, or only 3GB of address space? 
why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 32 bit process with LARGEADDRESSAWARE set can address 4GB on 64 bit Windows.  It can do so because that's how the wonderful engineers at Microsoft implemented it.

It's documented [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=889654).

Comment: from the link:
Virtual address space per 32-bit process: 2 GB, 4 GB if the application is compiled with the /LARGEADDRESSAWARE switch

Answer (score 2):

maybe the anwser [is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639540/how-much-memory-can-a-32-bit-process-access-on-a-64-bit-operating-system)

A 32 bit process will access 2GB RAM, with the LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag, it reaches the 4GB

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hiltonl/archive/2007/04/13/the-3gb-not-4gb-ram-problem.aspx

http://www.oldunreal.com/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1200330824

Answer (score 0):

In most OSes your 32-bit space is broken up into parts that you're program(user-code) can allocate and use, and sections that the kernel owns.   Unless you're writing your own OS/kernel let the system APIs(such as malloc/free, new/delete in C/C++) or the the underlying management in python, java manage the memory allocation for you.

However, if you're getting 'out of memory' errors start to consider

1. Do I have a leak somewhere?   You're not *free'ing* every pointer you're *malloc'ing*
   Wonderous tools such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) can help find those.
2. Do I need to redesign my program to use less memory?   Are you doing things like saving every line of data you read out of a huge file in an array in python or java.  Look for stuff you can throw away

Comment: is this the answer to a different question?