# memory error when reading from multiple files

Tags: python, memory, iterator, out-of-memory

I am reading in 15 files that are located in a folder on my desktop.  I can read in the first few files no problem but when i get a little more into it I end up getting a memory error that looks to be caused by Pythons built in iterator.  Just a note, I am using multiple lists to hold all the data because I am using 32bit python and they fill up very quickly since the files are so large.

```
x=0 #represents the file being read
for file in glob.glob(path): #reads all files in a folder
    with open(file) as f: 
        print (f)
        for line in f:    
            if "jack" in line: 

                if(x<=3):#prevent memory error
                    jack1.append(line)

                elif(x>3 and x<=6):
                    jack2.append(line)

                elif(x>6 and x<=8):
                    jack3.append(line)

                elif(x>8 and x<=9):#prevent memory error with try except 
                    try:
                        jack4.append(line)

                    except:
                        jack5.append(line)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\erik.kniaz\workspace\arif help\jack.py", line 102, in <module>
for line in f:    
MemoryError
```

Comment: line 102 is: for line in f:

Comment: Looks more like caused by you storing all the data in memory. Do you have to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using 32bit python

There's your problem.  32-bit processes, [generally speaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639540/how-much-memory-can-a-32-bit-process-access-on-a-64-bit-operating-system), are limited to 4 [GB](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/06/11/9725386.aspx) of virtual memory each, minus kernel space, which can be significant.  You will need to either switch to 64-bit computing or redesign your program to consume less memory.  This is normally done by pushing data back out to the filesystem instead of keeping it in memory.