# How do I switch from Python 64-bit to 32?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.4 on Windows 8. I'm thinking of changing as some packages do not work with 64-bit. If I do change to 32, will it affect the programs that I wrote on 64?

Comment: Python is Python, bottom line. Additionally, 64 bits is backwards compatible with 32 bits. That's why you'll see notation as `x86_64` and `x86`.

Comment: So, what is your _precise_ problem with the 64 bits version?

Comment: I've been trying to install the PyEnchant package but it does not work on 64-bit. I've been reading around and many people suggest using 32-bit over 64, for this reason of package compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Python code won't be affected, not much. You won't be able to [allocate as much memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639540/how-much-memory-can-a-32-bit-process-access-on-a-64-bit-operating-system), mostly. That's about it.

If you have 3rd party libraries installed that make use of C extensions, you'll have to reinstall 32-bit versions of those (or compile them yourself).

Comment: Ok. So how would you do it then?

Comment: How would you switch from Python 64-bit to 32-bit?

Comment: @Sid: reinstall Python2. Look at what 3rd-party projects you are using and if they include any `.dll` files, if so, re-install those. Done.