# c++ bad allocation when matrix size exceeds a certain limit with Eigen matrix type

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

In a c++ dynamic library I solve a least square problem using the [Eigen Library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page). This Dll is called inside a python software where the problem configuration is settled. In a small sized problem the code works properly and returns the correct solution. If the number of points increases then the library throws `std::bad_alloc`.

More precisely, The code which creates the error simplified to its most is

```
try {
    matrixA = new Eigen::MatrixXd(sizeX,NvalidBtuple); // initialize A
    for (int i=0;i<sizeX;++i) {
        int secondIndex = 0;
        for (int k=0;k<btermSize;++k) {
            if (bterm[k] == 1) {                        // select btuple that are validated by density exclusion
                // product of terms
                (*matrixA)(i,secondIndex) = 1.0;
                secondIndex += 1;
            }
        }
    }
} catch (std::bad_alloc& e) {
    errorString = "Error 3: bad allocation in computation of coefficients!";
    std::cout<<errorString<<" "<<e.what()<<std::endl;
    return;
} catch (...) {
    errorString = "Error 4: construction of matrix A failed! Unknown error.";
    std::cout<<errorString<<std::endl;
    return;
}
```

where `matrixA` is defined in the header file with `Eigen::MatrixXd *matrixA;`.

if `sizeX` and `NvalidBtuple` are smaller than about 20'000x3'000, the matrix definition works. If the size is bigger, it crashes.

The computer on which I did the tests has enough memory available, about 15G of free memory.

Is this a heap/stack problem?
How can I make the library accept bigger matrices?

Any comment is welcom. Thanks.

**Edit:**
As remarked in an answer below, I was not clear on the `NvalidBtuple` defintion:

```
NvalidBtuple = 0;
for (int i=0;i<btermSize;++i) {NvalidBtuple += bterm[i];}
```

where `bterm` is a boolean vector. Thus, since in the loop we do the check `if (bterm[k] == 1)`, the `secondIndex` is always smaller than `NvalidBtuple`.

Comment: Just to make sure: You are compiling as 64 bit, right?

Comment: No I am compiling in 32bits.

Comment: Then most of your 15G of free memory will be useless and only 2GB (or was it 3?) available to your application. Just as a side note...

Comment: Then I feel this is the problem. Because the matrix is close to 2GB size? If I compile in 64 bit will the library still work on a 32bit machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the details of your question, the matrix takes 480Mb of RAM. A 32bit application can only access 2Gb of RAM (see e.g. [How much memory can a 32 bit process access on a 64 bit operating system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639540/how-much-memory-can-a-32-bit-process-access-on-a-64-bit-operating-system)); the allocation fails because there is no free *continuous* 480Mb block in the address space of the application.

The best way to solve the problem is to recompile the application as 64 bit. You won't be able to run it in a 32 bit system, but this shouldn't be a problem since you aren't able to run your algorithm on such a system anyways due to the limited memory.