# COMException Out Of Server Memory

Tags: c#, com, out-of-memory, arcgis, esri

I'm working with ArcGIS 10.3.1 by using COM.

But now I have receive some problem, probably with some memory issues.

First I receive some `COMException (0x80041501): Operation Failed
at ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IRaster.Read(IPnt tlc, IpixelBlock block)`.

After a while of errors we see another `COMException (0x8004150D): Out of server memory at ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IRaster.Read(IPnt tlc, IpixelBlock block)`.

And after another while I get errors that say cannot read data etc...

Some settings for my computer:

- Running on a Windows 7 professional x64
- Now the computer have 32gb RAM.
- My Microsoft SQL server is allowed to use 2gb RAM.
- My application is build in 32bit and only uses max 1.7gb RAM on crash.
- Some application have cached like 5gb RAM
- Other applications only take like 1gb RAM

My application shall be able to handle almost 4gb RAM and with this configuration I should be able to use like 20-22gb ram.

Where can I start searching for my error(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Your application is near the memory use limit for a 32-bit app.  [Read more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639540/how-much-memory-can-a-32-bit-process-access-on-a-64-bit-operating-system)  If possible, try building it in AnyCPU mode.