# Alternative Way to Load Large Json File

Tags: python, json, pandas, large-files, ijson

I am trying to load a large `json` file (around 4G) as a `pandas dataframe`, but the following method does not work for file > around 2G. Is there any alternative method?

`data_dir = 'data.json'
 my_data = pd.read_json(data_dir, lines = True)`

I tried `ijson` but have no idea how to covert it to a `dataframe`.

Comment: What's your ram? Did you try the built in `json.loads`?

Comment: Are you using 32 bit or 64 bit python?

Comment: @JonasAdler I'm going to go ahead with the assumption that he's using 32-bit python the [~2GB limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/639562/4022608) would too much of a coincidence otherwise.

Comment: To the comments above, I am using a 64-bit with 8GB and I still had 55% left so ideally it should work :). Anyway, thanks to your advice with `json.loads` it's working now.

Comment: it is not because the file on disk is 4GB that the representation in memory is 4GB. Python creates an object for every string which might take more place than on disk.

Answer (score 1):

Loading the Large document in memory may not be best approach in this case. This size of JSON may require you to use a different approach for parsing. Try using Streaming parsers instead. Some options

https://pypi.org/project/json-stream-parser/

https://pypi.org/project/ijson/

The key is to not load the entire document in memory. This is similar to SAX parsing in the XML world.

I am not a python expert, however, there should be a good library that can already do it for you.