# IIS8 enable 32bit applications

Tags: iis-8, windows-server-2012, windows-server, wow64

I have a server Windows Server 2012 with 8GB RAM.

When I used `Enable 32-Bit Applications` in IIS, what is the maximum RAM can I use with this option?

What is the difference in RAM loaded with set enable 32 bit applications to true and false?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much memory can a 32 bit process access on a 64 bit operating system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639540/how-much-memory-can-a-32-bit-process-access-on-a-64-bit-operating-system)

Comment: I have 64 bit application but I have 2 32 bit dll so I want to use  32 bit mode and 64 bit in the same pool to benfit from 8 gb of RAM

Comment: It is impossible. You can only load 32 bit dll in a 32 bit process.

Comment: What is the benefit from using multiple worker processes?

Answer (score 0):

> When I used enable 32 bit application What is the maximum ram can I used with this option?

Each App Pool Worker Process will be limited to 4GB of memory.  A 32bit process has only a 4GB Virtual Address Space, and on 64bit Windows a 32bit process doesn't have any reservation in that 4GB for kernel memory (like on 32bit Windows).  Note that an App Pool can have multiple worker processes if you want.